# ExpressionEngine - displaying most recent 3 entries of each channel, followed by random (but non-repeating) entries

Tags: random, expressionengine

I need to output the most recent 3 entries from 4 different channels, followed by random entries from any of the four channels, but not including any of the most recent entries. Any idea how to accomplish this? I know how to display random entries, and I know how to display the 3 most recent entries of a channel, but not how to do the two things combined.

Comment: Please consider reposting at expressionengine.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks - will post there. Didn't know it existed.

Comment: See answers here: 
http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/734/expression-engine-displaying-most-recent-3-entries-of-each-channel-followed-b/747#747

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great answer was provided in the new stack exchange site:

https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/734/expressionengine-displaying-most-recent-3-entries-of-each-channel-followed-by

Answer (score 0):

Like this? a bit clunky but works..

```
 {exp:channel:entries channel="about" limit="3"}
  ..content..
 {/exp:channel:entries}

 {exp:channel:entries channel="news" limit="3"}
  .content..
 {/exp:channel:entries}

 {exp:channel:entries channel="services" limit="3"}
 ..content..
 {/exp:channel:entries}

 {exp:channel:entries channel="about|news|services" limit="1000"}
 ..content..
 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

You should check this out site, if you want more answers:

http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Comment: That works except for the last bit - it's not random and it doesn't keep you from repeating the entries in the previous 3 tags

Comment: sorry forgot to mention add parameter offset="3", and you could also use orderby="random"

Comment: You probably have to add more sets of channel entries so not mix the channels, ie. not use channel="about|news|services"